# Regex: Only allow a character if another character has been found in a string

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to exclude the use of certain characters if another character has been found already?

For example, in a phone number field 123-456-7890 and 123.456.7890 are valid, but 123-456.7890 is not.

at the minute i have:

```
static String pattern = "\\d{3}[-.]\\d{3}[-.]\\d{4}";
```

How can this be improved to fulfill the above requirement?

To clarify, it will be used in a string, which will be compiled to a Pattern object:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
```

Then used in a Matcher:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(phoneNumber);
if(m.find()){
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with [**back reference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) that matches the same text as previously matched by a capturing group.

You need to add `-` and `.` in a capturing group using `(...)` that can be referred in next match using `\index_of_group`

```
              \d{3}([-.])\d{3}\1\d{4}
Captured Group 1----^^^^      ^^-------- Back Reference first matched group
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pT7hX1/1)

Sample code:

```
System.out.print("123-456-7890".matches("^\\d{3}([-.])\\d{3}\\1\\d{4}$"));//true
System.out.print("123.456.7890".matches("^\\d{3}([-.])\\d{3}\\1\\d{4}$"));//true
System.out.print("123-456.7890".matches("^\\d{3}([-.])\\d{3}\\1\\d{4}$"));//false
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [-.]                     any character of: '-', '.'
  )                        end of \1
  \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
```

Comment: You need to give a little more info, so I'm just gonna add it in a comment. The parentheses around the first `[-.]` make it what is  called a capturing group. These groups can be referenced with `\[number of group]` where the 0 is the entire match.

Comment: works fine in the demo, but when i try to make this a string and run it through a Matcher object it doesn't work?